# How to pass facebook redirect_uri user_omniauth_authorize_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

In my Rails controller I have something like:

```
 def authenticate_user!
    if not current_user
      # TODO: after login user should go back to the place she tried to get, not ref url
      redirect_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/some-page-where-user-redirected-after-login')
    end
  end
```

How to pass the right facebook redirect_uri in user_omniauth_authorize_path?

I tried ":redirect_uri => " but it doesn't work.

I need to redirect user to the add comment form after she logins. Login is done through Facebook Omniauth Devise only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your currently signing the user in something like this:

```
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
```

then you can change to:

```
  sign_in @user, :event => :authentication
  @after_sign_in_url = 'url'
  render 'page to render'
```